# Питон не видит файл в директории

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
fileLocation = open("2.txt")
print(fileLocation)
```

Не видит этот файл, хоть он 100% есть и находится в моей директории.

Выдает ошибку:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2.txt'

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137654/discussion-on-question-by-typicall-l------).

Comment: файл-то в твоей директории. А питон?

Answer (score 4):

Только что столкнулся с этой проблемой и нашёл решение. Но прежде - если вы работаете в VS Code - проверьте, откуда в терминале запускается файл. Если нужно будет - перейдите в терминале в нужную директорию через команду cd. Или же попробуйте запустить файл не в IDE.

В моём случае оказалось, что VS Code запускал файл из другой папки. Это выглядело так:

- Папка_1

  - Папка_2

    - Папка_3.1

      - Искомый_файл
      - Программа.py
    - Папка_3.2

VS Code запускал программу, условно, из D:\Папка_1, в то время как нужно было из D:\Папка_1\Папка_2\Папка_3.1. Я узнал это, получив путь файла с помощью следующего кода:

```
import os, sys

# Выводит абсолютный путь программы D:\Папка_1\Папка_2\Папка_3.1\Программа.py
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# Выводит путь к папке с программой D:\Папка_1\Папка_2\Папка_3.1\
print(os.getcwd())
```

Почему и как VS Code запускал программу не из того файла, в котором она лежала? Понятия не имею.

Если ваша IDE запускает файл не там, где нужно, то вы это узнаете, и увидите, откуда она его запускает второй командой - os.getcwd().

Если это не помогает и путь правильный - проверьте, какие файлы вообще видит программа с помощью следующего кода:

```
# Выводит список из файлов, лежащих в настоящей директории: ['Искомый_файл', 'Программа.py']
print(os.listdir())
```

Если в выведенном списке будут все имеющиеся в папке файлы за исключением только искомого - то возможно проблема в самом файле.